# Use reverse geocoding to get an address as variable output

Tags: javascript, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to make it so when a truck driver presses a button when he starts for the day, i can see what his location is at that very moment so i know where my drivers are starting from.

I am trying to get it when someone gives access to their location you can get a straight address out of it as a variable. it just needs to be city and a country.

like this: Nottingham, NG1 1AJ, UK
Here the link as an example: https://www.mapdevelopers.com/what-is-my-address.php

i can only find reverse geocoding where it just shows the location on the map.
below code uses reverse geocoding but gets an address on a map.
i am trying to get it as a variable output to show in an app.
Thanks for the help!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Geolocation</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" id="get_location"><button>Get location</button></a>

    <div id="map">
      <iframe
        id="google_map"
        width="1000"
        height="700"
        frameborder="0"
        scrolling="no"
        marginheight="0"
        marginwidth="0"
        src="https://maps.google.com?output=embed"
      ></iframe>
    </div>

    <script>
      var x = document.getElementById("demo");
      function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
          x.innerHTML = "Locatie niet supported door jouw browser.";
        }
      }

      function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML =
          "Latitude: " +
          position.coords.latitude +
          "<br>Longitude: " +
          position.coords.longitude;
      }

      var c = function (pos) {
        var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
        long = pos.coords.longitude;
        coords = lat + ", " + long;

        document
          .getElementById("google_map")
          .setAttribute(
            "src",
            "https://maps.google.com/?q=" + coords + "0&z=60&output=embed"
          );
      };

      document.getElementById("get_location").onclick = function () {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(c);
        return false;
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you able to use the [Google Maps Reverse Geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)? Is that what you're wanting to use to achieve this?

Comment: hi @Phil, no this is not what i want to use. i want it to be free actually. any other way or idea on how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer for it, see below code.

//only works with google maps API key

```
<script src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXYOUR_API_KEYXXXX&callback=initMap&v=weekly&channel=2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
window.onload=getGeo;


function getGeo(){
    if (navigator && navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoOK, geoKO);
    } else {
        geoMaxmind();
    }
}

function geoOK(position) {
     showLatLong(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
}
function geoMaxmind() {
     showLatLong(geoip_latitude(), geoip_longitude());
}

function geoKO(err) {
if (err.code == 1) {
error('De gebruiker heeft toestemming geweigerd om locatie-informatie te verkrijgen.');
} else if (err.code == 2) {
error('Uw locatie kan niet worden bepaald.');
} else if (err.code == 3) {
error('TimeOut.')
} else {
error('We weten niet wat er is gebeurd, maar er is een fout opgetreden.');
}
}

function showLatLong(lat, longi) {
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var yourLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, longi);
geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': yourLocation },processGeocoder);

}
function processGeocoder(results, status){

if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
if (results[0]) {
document.forms[0].dir.value=results[0].formatted_address;
document.getElementById("")
} else {
error('Google heeft geen resultaten opgeleverd.');
}
} else {
error("Geocodering mislukt vanwege: " + status);
}
}
function error(msg) {
alert(msg);
}
</script>

<form align="left">
        <input type="text" name="dir" />
</form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).